# Audio only output via my PC to hifi DAC using the VLC app on my ipad

Tags: audio

Using windows10 on my Desktop PC with attached hard disk music storage all in FLAC format..

Access to all of my music files is either directly from my PC via JRiver or by the JRiver app on my iPad. My PC is connected to my hifi amp/DAC and as such the volume etc is controlled from there.

I am not interested in accessing or playing video content.

I’m simply looking for an alternative to JRiver accessed via an app on my iPad

So far VLC displays all of my music files and plays them with output only available on my iPad. Tried multiple variations of audio only settings on VLC but cannot get output enabled through to my hifi DAC via spdif.

Any help would & advice would be appreciated.
Roger Harris

Comment: https://wiki.videolan.org/Control_VLC_from_an_iPhone/